# Testing SwiftUI body views and properties

Tags: ios, swift, tdd, swiftui

I'm in the process of working out how to unit test SwiftUI view code.

I have the following definition:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello World")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold) 
    }
}
```

and I can test it like this:

```
    func testBody() {
        let cv = ContentView()

        let body = cv.body

        XCTAssertNotNil(body)

        guard let text = body as? Text else { XCTFail(); return }

        XCTAssertEqual(Text("Hello World").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold), text)
    }
```

however, as soon as I want to test text alignment, I run into issues:

production code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello World")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
}
```

and test code:

```
    func testBody() {
        let cv = ContentView()

        let body = cv.body

        XCTAssertNotNil(body)

        guard let text = body as? Text else { XCTFail(); return }

        // COMPILER ERROR ON NEXT LINE
        XCTAssertEqual(Text("Hello World").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.leading), text)  
    }
```

...then I get the following compiler error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to expected argument type '_ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HAlignment>>'`

How do I test the alignment of the `Text` struct?

Comment: Have you tried casting `text` to `'_ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HAlignment>>'` instead of `Text`?

Comment: Unfortunantely that productes a further compiler error: 

`Global function 'XCTAssertEqual(_:_:_:file:line:)' requires that '_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HAlignment>' conform to 'Equatable'`

Answer (score 4):

There are two extensions for `.font(_:)`, namely:

```
extension View {
    /// Sets the default font for text in this view.
    ///
    /// - Parameter font: The default font to use in this view.
    /// - Returns: A view with the default font set to the value you supply.
    public func font(_ font: Font?) -> Self.Modified<_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Font?>>
}
```

and

```
extension Text {
    /// Sets the font to use when displaying this text.
    ///
    /// - Parameter font: The font to use when displaying this text.
    /// - Returns: Text that uses the font you specify.
    public func font(_ font: Font?) -> Text
}
```

When you execute the method .font on a `Text` struct, **you will get back a new `Text`**, with the applied font because it calls the overload of `font(_:)` (creating an overloaded method with a more specific return type is always ok). When you call the font method on, for example, a `Button`, the return type is:

```
ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Font?>>
```

Well, that's no normal `Button` anymore, but a wrapped pretty complex type, because it doesn't have it's own overload like Text has, so it calls the 'normal' method.

What happend when you called `multilineTextAlignment` on your `Text` instance?

```
extension View {

    /// Sets the alignment of multiline text in this view.
    ///
    /// - Parameter alignment: A value you use to align lines of text to the
    ///   left, right, or center.
    /// - Returns: A view that aligns the lines of multiline `Text` instances
    ///   it contains.
    public func multilineTextAlignment(_ alignment: HAlignment) -> Self.Modified<_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HAlignment>>
}
```

There is no overload of `Text`, like there is for the font method. It means the return type is different than a new `Text` instance. Now we are stuck with a complex time.

There is, fortunately, a `content` property for that complex type. Your test will compile when doing this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(Text("Hello World").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).content, text)
```

Noticed the `content` property :)?

When running the test, the `body` variable isn't of type `Text`, like you would expect, but has another very complex type, that's why your test will fail. To pass your test, do the following:

```
func testBody() {
    let cv = ContentView()

    let body = cv.body

    XCTAssertNotNil(body)

    // Yuk!! Ugly cast, but don't know how to fix it since yeah, it is the type of the body...
    guard let text = body as? (_ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HAlignment>>) else { XCTFail(); return }

    // No compile error :) and a passing test!
    XCTAssertEqual(Text("Hello World").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).content, text.content)
}
```

Comment: I tried you solution but I'm getting this errors. ``` Use of undeclared type '_ModifiedContent'``` and also ```Use of unresolved identifier 'Text' ``` . I'm using this version of Xcode Version 11.0 (11A419c)

Comment: @user2924482 Only thing I can guess is that you missed an import statement

Comment: what did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewInspector](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector) library for unit testing the SwiftUI hierarchy:

```
let view = ContentView()
let string = try view.inspect().text().string()
XCTAssertEqual(string, "Hello, world!")
```